# rman backup takes too long time on oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I have a problem that my RMAN backup on our sl45 tape drive takes 2 days to backup 450GB database. The problem that the log shows is that the backup waits too long between finishing a certain task and starting another task.

#### Example:

> ```
> Finished backup at 21-MAR-2019:19:28:01
> Starting backup at 22-MAR-2019:08:33:21
> ```

These 2 tasks are in the same backup session. I don't know why it takes so long time between tasks.

#### Backup script:

```
connect target /;
run {
    allocate channel ch1 type  'sbt_tape' parms 'ENV=(OB_MEDIA_FAMILY=IMC_ONLINE_DB)' ;
    allocate channel ch2 type  'sbt_tape' parms 'ENV=(OB_MEDIA_FAMILY=IMC_ONLINE_DB)' ;
    sql'ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG CURRENT';
    BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
...
...
```

Does anybody have an idea why I might be encountering such issues?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for your participation. Could you possibly include your whole backup script? I'm asking, because there's a missing closing curly brace `}` which in turn indicates that there is more to it than meets the eye. Enterprise or Standard Edition?